# Послать содержимое <input type='files' multiple> с xmlhttp на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, input, xmlhttprequest

Не получается переслать файлы на сервер вместе с другими данными.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id='my_file' name="my_file[]" accept='image/*' multiple>
```

Код JS:

```
//
var data = new FormData();
var fp = $("#my_file");
var id= // some value

for(var i=0, len=fp[0].files.length; i<len; i++) 
    data.append('my_file[]', fp[0].files[i]); 

var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); 
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/or/save.php', true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
xmlhttp.send("id=" + id + "&" + "data=" + data);
```

На сервере в save.php проверяю при помощи `print_r($FİLES)`. Проблема в коде, на сервере всё норм. В чём ошибка?

Следующий код работает, но он без ajax

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept='\image'>
        <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
            $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
            $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
            echo print_r($_FILES);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                ?>
                    <p>File #<?= $i+1 ?>:</p>
                    <p>

                        Name: <?= $myFile["name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Temporary file: <?= $myFile["tmp_name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Type: <?= $myFile["type"][$i] ?><br>
                        Size: <?= $myFile["size"][$i] ?><br>
                        Error: <?= $myFile["error"][$i] ?><br>
                    </p>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключается в этой строке:

```
xmlhttp.send("id=" + id + "&" + "data=" + data);
```

Вы пытаетесь отправить массив data как строку. Правильно будет так:

```
data.append('id', id);
xhr.send(data);
```

Полная версия:

```
    var data = new FormData();
    var fp   = document.querySelector('#my_file');

    for (var i = 0; i < fp.files.length; i++) {
        data.append('my_file[]', fp.files[i]);
    }

    data.append('id', id);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/or/save.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form'));
jQuery.ajax('/endpoint.php', {
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData
});
```

Как то так можно

Comment: Мне нужно одновременно отправить файлы вместе с  другой информацей из других блоков

Comment: так там будет все, это прям вся форма сендится

Comment: Но другие блоки не в этой форме

Comment: отправь 2 формы

Comment: К тому же одна форма тож не отправляется. Вы проверяли свой код?

Comment: Почитай может поможет https://habrahabr.ru/post/154097/